# Wait for *user* service to gracefully exit before machine shutdown/reboot

Tags: linux, shutdown, services, reboot, systemd

I've been managing all my user level processes using `systemctl --user`, which provides a lot of great benefits including the ability to auto-restart on error, process dependencies, etc.

However, one problem I've been having is that reboots/poweroff doesn't wait for user services to end. I've seen quite a bit of info about system services, but nothing about user services.

Here's some interesting information I've found:

- [How systemd reboot/poweroff work internally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211924/effect-of-reboot-signal-on-systemd-service-state)
- [Systemd system services are indeed supposed to stop cleanly](https://serverfault.com/questions/904346/wait-for-service-to-gracefully-exit-before-machine-shutdown-reboot)
- [Someone else has the same problem I do, but phrased it differently](https://serverfault.com/questions/878344/behaviour-of-systemd-services-on-reboot)

Upon further investigation, I found that services do get the signal to terminate. The problem is that systemd doesn't wait for them to gracefully finish. Surprisingly, not all my user services get terminated though, event though `linger` is disabled for my user. I can test this by logging out of my graphical session, logging in to TTY as root, and `ps`ing to see what processes are stil running.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently processes running in the `user.slice` are killed (mercilessly) within about 90 s after a shutdown command is issued, as opposed to processes running in the `system.slice`.

I assume processes started by `systemctl --user` end up in the `user.slice`.

I had a similar problem caused by a user switch (`su`/`sudo`) in my startscript used to start my service (`ExecStart=/path/to/my/startscript`).

After removing `su`/`sudo` in the startscript and adding `User=myuser` to the `[Service]` section of the unit file, my service processes started in the `system.slice` and got handled correctly on shutdown.

Comment: in case people find this question, found this answer while researching another https://serverfault.com/questions/1137788 . be warned, things changed since 2019. systemd will not wait 90s before mercilessly killing your `user.slice` processes, it will kill them immediately now.